# Edited, but no changes? Why in reopen review queue, if nothing changed?

Tags: bug, editing, voting-to-reopen

[image]

This looks like a bug to me:

- If nothing* changed, why push it to reopen queue?
- If something* changed, why not to show it?

This is the question I'm talking about: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/134668/drupal-form-placeholder

---

* By nothing, I mean nothing important / significant

Comment: Hmm yes, does smell like a bug. There were changes made in that edit: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/134668/revisions. Perhaps something to do with the small gap in time between closing and editing? Just speculating

Comment: @Clive or some rejected suggested edit after? Or mechanism that detects and hides formatting changes without content changes? Because nothing major changed there. Don't know, and don't really care, I can't avoid it anyway.

Comment: This is another one http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/41272 under Reopen Votes

Answer (score -1):

Repo here, I hit **leave closed**, pointless review!!!

> [image]

Comment: The point is - there *are* changes... Hit "skip" if bug does not allow you to review it honestly.